# Recibir tabla de postgres en java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, servlets

Tengo la siguiente funcion en postgresql :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_sel_categoria(IN _codigo integer)
RETURNS TABLE(acat_cod smallint, acat_nombre character varying, acat_descrip character varying) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF _codigo =-1 THEN
return query 
SELECT cat_cod, cat_nombre, cat_descrip
FROM categoria
order by cat_nombre;            
ELSE    
return query 
SELECT cat_cod, cat_nombre, cat_descrip
FROM categoria
WHERE cat_cod = _codigo
order by cat_nombre;    

END IF; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 900001;
ALTER FUNCTION public.sp_sel_categoria(integer)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Al recibirla en java lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
while (resultado.next())
{
EntCategoria categoria = new EntCategoria();
categoria.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("acat_cod "));
categoria.setNombre(resultado.getString("acat_nombre "));
listCategorias.add(categoria);               
}
```

el problema surge porque quiero recibirla con el nombre de la columna
pero me salta el siguiente error:

The column name acat_cod was not found in this ResultSet.

y si lo hago por numero de columna me muestra el siguiente error:

Bad value for type int : -,RECUERDOS,"NO DEFINIDO"

Como recibo esa tabla generada en postgres en java

Comment: En el SELECT la columna se llama `cat_cod` no `acat_cod`. O bien cambias el código Java o bien creas un alias en el SELECT: `SELECT cat_cod AS acat_cod...`

Comment: pero asi le ponga por el mismo nombre no me permite porque hace referencia a toda la fila, quiero saber si se puede obtener un elemento especifico de ese array que devuelve

Answer (score 0):

A ver los metodos getters son para consultar sus cabeceras son private tipodato getNombre();
los metodos getters no reciben parametros si no que los devuelven la solucion:

```
while (resultado.next())
{
  EntCategoria categoria = new EntCategoria();
  categoria.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("acat_cod "));
  //eliminar parametros del metodo getInt()

  categoria.setNombre(resultado.getString("acat_nombre "));
  //eliminar parametros de la llamada a la funcion getString()

  listCategorias.add(categoria);               
}
```

Comment: pero uso setter para almacenarlos y el getter para la cabecera de la columna, luego los añado a la lista que sera usada pero el problema es que quiero tomar el valor de cada columna de la tabla resultante

Comment: O recoges todo el resultado de todas las columnas fila por fila en una lista de string y luego separas los diferentes campos, o creas un objeto el cual contenga esos datos de todas las columnas de cada fila, y haces una lista de esos objetos, si los tipos fuesen todos del mismo tipo por ejemplo string , podrias guardarlo en una matriz que tenga el mismo numero de columnas que la tabla resultante a la consulta

Comment: tuve que hacerlo tomando toda la fila y separando por comas porque de la otra forma lo hacia mediante una consulta normal pero ahora que uso funciones no puedo hacerlo como antes